# RegEx Find a string that contains a pattern and variables

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is an example string I want to find:

```
var test = "High=50";
var test2 = "Low=-8.7";
```

Both the low and high string's number range can be from -9.99 - 99.99. Here is a regex that I have tried but doesn't work:

```
var highPattern = "/High=/^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$"
```

But when I try

```
var highRegExp = new RegExp(highPattern);

if(highRegExp.test(test)){
    alert("true");
}else{alert("flase")}
```

It returns false every time.

Tim, in the comments asked why I need regex here. Let me explain, I am testing a string that might be built like: "Low=2 High=15.5". If my DOM gets updated, and the high value changes I need to remove "High=15.5" and add "High=20". The numerical range can be anywhere from -9.99 to 99.99.

Comment: I would recommend checking numerical ranges by...checking the numerical range in JavaScript, not using a regex.  Is there some reason why you think you need a regex here?

Comment: Are you trying to validate such strings? Just use `/^(?:High|Low)=-?(\d*\.?\d+)$/` and then check the Group 2 (if it is in the allowed range) with JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure the format:

`new RegExp(/^(High|Low)\=-{0,1}\d{1,2}\.\d{2}$/).test("High=-0.12")`

if you want to extract the number you could also use (easier to read, compared to a regex)

`Number(test.split("=")[1])`

**Edit:**

This one also checks for range (-9.99 to 99.99):

`^(High|Low)\=(-[0-9]{1}|[0-9]{1,2})(\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}$`

Comment: I dont wan't to extract the number, I want to remove the part of the string that matches the true expression.

Comment: Upon further testing, it appears that "High=32" returns false.

Comment: already updated the regex - try again. Also just one addition: It does not do proper range checking. This would require some additional tweaking of the syntax

Comment: @BenderBending ...sorry - also check out the 2nd variant which does a simple check on the range

Comment: It looks like that whole numbers are goign though, so we just need to make the decimal point and the decimal numbers optional in the regexp

Comment: decimal is optional now (updated reply) - I'd recommend to add such details in the question next time too. BR

Comment: The updated regexp is working correctly. Sorry, when I said range = -9.99-99.99 I assumed others would know that it included int values as well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: please update your answer to: new RegExp(/^(High|Low)\=(-)?([0-9]{1}|[0-9]{1,2})(\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}$/)

Answer (score 2):

Well, answering your question you can use `/=-?\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?/`, example:

```
let reg = /=-?\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?/;
alert(reg.test("High=50"));
alert(reg.test("Low=-8.7"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following RegEx:

```
\-?[0-9]{1,2}\.?[0-9]{0,2}
```